Spark HDInsight cluster deployment fails with internal server error
I have tried deploying a Spark HDInsight 5.1.3 cluster twice, and each time the deployment fails with an internal server error. I took all of the default settings except using an existing storage account and virtual network. Error Json is below
"statusMessage": "{\"status\":\"Failed\",
   \"error\":{\"code\":\"ResourceOperationFailure\",
   \"message\":\"The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.\",
   \"details\":[{
         \"code\":\"InternalServerError\",
         \"message\":\"Internal server error occurred while processing the request. Please retry the request or contact support.\"}]}}", 
"eventCategory": "Administrative",
        "entity": "/subscriptions/xxx/resourcegroups/MPCS53014RG/providers/Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/myclustername",
        "message": "Microsoft.HDInsight/clusters/write",

       "hierarchy": "yyy/Production-Management-Group/zzz"    },
    "relatedEvents": []

}


could you add your template to your question please? also is the storage attached to the  vnet?
